# How to find joint pdf

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables

The random arrival of $k$ phone calls within a time interval of length $t$ is described by the following pdf

$$f(t) = \frac{\lambda^k}{(k-1)!} t^{k-1} e^{-\lambda t}$$

where parameter $\lambda$ represents the arrival rate and the arrivals are assumed to be independent of each other.

(a) Assume that $n$ time intervals $t_0, t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_{n-1} $ during which always the same number of $k$ phone calls occurred have been made. What is the joint pdf describing these measurements or observations?

I dunno how to approach this problem. I tried to find the product of $f(t)$ for each $t$ but I have a feeling that is wrong. Please kindly help.

Comment: So is $t$ (or $T$) is the random variable here?  Are the $N$ (or $n$) time intervals independent?  If so, what is wrong with your idea of the product $\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} f(t_i)$?